# Returning unexpected None value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def sort_by_length(words):
    if words!=None:
        words= words.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    return words

def single_sort_by_len_test(input, result):
    assert result == sort_by_length(list(input))

single_sort_by_len_test(["dog", "apple", "bear"], ["apple", "bear", "dog"])
```

Here words is returning a `None` value. But the answer should be `["apple", "bear", "dog"]`. Couldn't see where the problem is.

Comment: `words.sort()` sorts in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if a method/function modifies an object, it will *not* return a result (just `None`).